# How to authorize and authenicate the GKE pods to run the Google DataflowRunners?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, gke-networking

I'm trying to run the google dataflow from GKE Pods. I wanted to know how to enforce the authorization and authentication to dataflow from GKE Pods (GKE -> Dataflow Compute VM).

Answer (score 0):

You could follow several methods which are explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform).

The easiest method is to enable and configure [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) on your Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters. Workload Identity allows workloads in your GKE clusters to impersonate Identity and Access Management (IAM) service accounts to access Google Cloud services